# Convert time stamp to seconds in bash

Tags: bash

As far as I know, bash variables do not have a certain type.

My problem is, I need to convert a time stamp (always in format: `hh:mm:ss`) to a single integer representing seconds.

So I cut the `hh`, `mm` and `ss` parts into separate strings and use `expr` to calculate the seconds integer like:

```
TIME=expr $HH \* 3600 + $MM \* 60 + $SS
```

But when e.g. `$HH=00` then expr won't work. Is it possible to convert strings like `00` or `01` to integers?

Comment: The command `date +%S` will print the current amount of seconds. What is the bash script you are using this in?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm recording radio broadcasts with gnutv. ffmpeg can cut the produced mpgs without reencoding but the syntax is kind of complicated so I want to write a script where I just have to enter the mpgs name and the start and end times (as well as Information about the interpret, the songs title, and so on, because ffmpeg should be able to edit metadata too).

Comment: So what you want it to do is start and stop at a specific time? You could even use `date +%s`, which apparently gives the `seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. That might be a bit complicated though... For more see the manual page `man date`.

Comment: The problem is (if I'm not mistaken) that ffmpeg accepts a start time (-ss option) but not an end time. Instead, it has a duration option which has to be entered in seconds. So the bash script would have to subtract the give start time from the end time and give the result as seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `awk`. For example:

```
echo "00:20:40" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'
```

So, if you have:

```
time="00:20:40"
```

then:

```
seconds=$(echo $time | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
```

and `echo $seconds` will print `1240`.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to convert the current time into second**, try this script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

let var=$(date +%H)*3600+$(date +%M)*60+$(date +%S)
echo $var
```

It will convert the current time into seconds (an integer).

**If you wish to convert an arbitrary time string** like `HH:MM:SS` into second then it is better to use [Radu Rădeanu's](https://askubuntu.com/a/407761/127327) answer. I could give something in the way you were trying,

I am assuming you stored hour, min, and second in `HH`, `MM` and `SS`, then use the following to store time in second into `var`,

```
let var=HH*3600+MM*60+SS
```

Answer (score 2):

If your timestamp is less than 24 hours you can use gnu date and convert to seconds after epoch (January 1st, 1970), by specifying UTC:

```bash
timestamp="23:59:59" # largest timestamp possible w/ this method
date -d "1970-01-01T${timestamp} UTC" "+%s"
```

Output:

```
104399
```

Comment: This only works if your timezone is UTC or if you set the `TZ` environment variable to `UTC0`